# Diameter of a graph with O(|V|) edges

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

What's the minimum diameter of a connected undirected graph with |V| vertices and O(|V|) edges?

Comment: I don't understand your question: you have supplied the upper bound you seem to be asking for?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You won't have a better upper bound than $O(V)$.  The "worst case" is a clique with a path coming out of it.  If the graph has a linear number of edges, the diameter can also be linear...

Comment: (1) I would say that the diameter can be ∞.  (The diameter of a graph is often defined to be ∞ if it is not connected.)  (2) Did you mean to ask for a _lower_ bound of the diameter?

Comment: Tsuyoshi Ito: I was thinking of connected graphs.

Comment: @Andras: I only gave an example for trees. A complete graph has diameter 1 (but O(|V|^2) edges). I will try to rephrase the question.

Comment: the min makes much more sense.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to minimize. Do you want (a) an upper bound that holds for all $O(|V|)$-edge graphs, or do you want (b) a family of graphs with $O(|V|)$ edges and minimum diameter? Note that Lev's comment is an answer for (a). Or do you want a hard upper bound on (a), with no big-O's, but rather a dependence on the constant $c$ for a $c |V|$-edge graph?

Comment: I think he wanted (b), but Aaron's answer takes care of that. I wonder if the trick is to require the graph to be regular, to make the problem more interesting.

Comment: If all degrees are at most $c$ then there's a lower-bound on diameter of $\Omega(\log_{c} |V|)$ because at most $c^d$ vertices are within distance $d$ of any single vertex. I presume that Aaron's example can be modified to show that this is tight.

Comment: Warren's analysis is tight as shown by balanced c-ary trees.

Comment: This is CS.Stackexchange.com level question, not CSTheory level. is less than undergrad student exercise.

Comment: See also the [degree diameter problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_diameter_problem) and the [Moore bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A line graph has O(V) edges and diameter V-1. A star graph also has O(V) edges and diameter 2. So it seems that the constraint that a graph has O(V) edges places almost no restriction at all on what the diameter can be.

Of course, 2 is the minimum, since only a complete graph has diameter 1.

Comment: arggh. stupid me. of course.

Comment: line graph -> path graph?

Answer (score -1):

In general I would say the biggest lower bound is 1, as the graph

```
a---b
```

has diameter 1 and has |V|/2 = O(|V|) edges.

The same holds for

```
a---b---c
+-------+
```

and

```
    +-------+
a---b---c---d
+-------+
```

which have exactly |V|, and |V|+1 = O(|V|) edges, respectively.

<s>This works for an arbitrary number of graphs, as long as you fix the number of nodes.</s>

If you restrict the number of edges not to O(|V|) but to |V|, you get a biggest lower bound of 2 for graphs of at least 4 nodes.

**EDIT**

Since the first and second example have diameter 1 with $|E| \leq |V|$ (so, clearly $|E| \in O(|V|)$) the statement that **each** such graph has at least diameter 2 does not hold.

Comment: What's the distance between vertex a and d in your last example? How would you do it for 5 nodes?

Comment: If someone says “the diameter of a graph with O(|V|) edges cannot be 1,” I think that a usual interpretation is that there does not exist an infinite sequence of graphs G_1, G_2, … and a constant c>0 such that the number of vertices tends to ∞, |E(G_i)|≤c|V(G_i)|, and the diameter of every G_i is equal to 1.

Comment: No, this is not an asymptotic statement. It says "for **every** graph with the property X the statement Y holds". This is a fundamentally different statement than "for every input the algorithms runs in O(Z(n))", where there may be a finite number of inputs where c*Z(n) does not hold. I'll edit my answer to stress this point.

Comment: Your last comment has two different issues.  (1) The statement “the diameter of a graph with O(|V|) edges cannot be 1” is an asymptotic statement, even if it does not look so to you.  You have interpreted the statement as something like “if a graph G satisfies |E(G)|≤c|V(G)| for some c>0, then the diameter of G cannot be 1” and disproved it, but this interpretation is simply nonsense.  (2) In my last comment, I did not say that |E(G_i)|≤c|V(G_i)| could be violated for finitely many values of i.  Therefore, your objection has nothing to do with my last comment.

Comment: By the way, I admit that the statement “the diameter of a graph with O(|V|) edges cannot be 1” is a little sloppy.  But I think that people use statements like this in the real world, and it should be understood as a statement about infinitely many graphs.